# R package doesn't detect updated version of GDAL

Tags: r, gdal, r-raster, rgdal

I am trying to shift from `raster` to the new `terra` R package, which requires a recent version of GDAL to be installed on my machine (MacOS 10.14.6).

I updated GDAL following the instructions here: http://www.alexchubaty.com/post/2020-01-08-using-latest-gdal-macos-redux/ and it seemed to work. When I run `gdalinfo --version` in the terminal it displays:

`GDAL 3.1.1, released 2020/06/22`

But when I load the `terra` library in R it still seems to link to an old version of GDAL (2.4.2):

```
> library(terra)
This is terra version 0.7.11 (alpha-release)

NOTE: You are using GDAL version 2.4.2 
For full functionality you need at least version 3.0.4
```

Interestingly, `rgdal` package seems to detect the updated version:

```
> library(rgdal)
Loading required package: sp
rgdal: version: 1.5-12, (SVN revision 1018)
Geospatial Data Abstraction Library extensions to R successfully loaded
Loaded GDAL runtime: GDAL 3.1.2, released 2020/07/07
Path to GDAL shared files: /usr/local/Cellar/gdal/3.1.2/share/gdal
GDAL binary built with GEOS: TRUE 
Loaded PROJ runtime: Rel. 7.1.0, August 1st, 2020, [PJ_VERSION: 710]
Path to PROJ shared files: /Users/jamesmccarthy/Library/Application Support/proj:/usr/local/opt/proj/share/proj:/usr/local/Cellar/proj/7.1.0/share/proj
PROJ CDN enabled:FALSE
Linking to sp version:1.4-2
To mute warnings of possible GDAL/OSR exportToProj4() degradation,
use options("rgdal_show_exportToProj4_warnings"="none") before loading rgdal.

Attaching package: ‘rgdal’

The following object is masked from ‘package:terra’:

    project
```

Does anyone know how to get `terra` to link to the most recent version of GDAL? I'm guessing the old version is still installed somewhere on the machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing that you installed `rgdal` from source, but the *binary version* of `terra` from CRAN. So after doing (what you already did) from the command line:

```
brew install pkg-config
brew install gdal
```

You should get what you are looking for with the following R command

```
install.packages("terra", type = "source")
```

Or, for the cutting edge

```
remotes::install_github("rspatial/terra")
```

Good luck with `terra`!